# UWP TextBox won't stretch in StackPanel

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I have a `TextBlock` and `TextBox` controls inside `StackPanel`, and I need to stretch `TextBox` to resize by the parent size in UWP.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Name:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="130" />
    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</StackPanel>
```

This not works.. Any ideas?

Comment: Swap StackPanel for Grid.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the stack panel will only stretch to the size of the child elements so in your example you will only see one Textblock of 130 pixels and you will not see the TextBox.

To get the functionality you desire you should use a grid with two columns one 130 pixels and the other being * to fill up the entire column space that is available.

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="130" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually wrap a `TextBlock` and `TextBox` pair inside a `DockPanel`

```
<DockPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" >
    <TextBlock Text="Name:" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="5"
               />
    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</DockPanel>
```

**Edit**

For UWP which doesn't have `DockPanel`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Name:" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="5"
                    />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: sorry, bad TAG, in UWP I dont have anything like DockaPanel :(

Comment: @Kicker You tagged correctly. I just assumed UWP had a `DockPanel` control like WPF. My edit may work but I don't have a way to test it.

Comment: @Kicker if you don't mind including a NuGet package in your project, the [UWP Community Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit) has a DockPanel for you.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a similar problem in UWP

```
    <StackPanel Margin="{StaticResource SmallTopBottomMargin}" Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="Project Name:" /> 
        <TextBox />    <--full width
        <TextBlock Text="Exported Template:" /> <--full width
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox />  <--max width - button width
            <Button Grid.Column="1">...</Button>
        </Grid>
```